# ReferenceError: state is not defined - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

i'm getting error state is not define while doing practice, as i check the document they are using same format to create state

```
function App() {

  // build state
  state = {
    Name:'Hamza',
    Status: 'Comitted'
  };
  // function
  ChangeProfile=()=>{
    this.setState({
      Name: 'Shahwar'
    });
    this.setState({
      Status: 'Divorced'
    });
    console.log('updated',this.state);
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{this.state.Name}</Text>
      <Text>{this.state.Status}</Text>
      <Button title="Click Me!" onPress={this.ChangeProfile} />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Show more context, please. This is not enough to code to help you.

Comment: Is this a class component? Where is your `render` method?

Comment: no `this` in FCs. Use `useState` hook to add state logic in FC.

Comment: can you please show example because i'm learner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to mix class based and functional base. Your code should be like this.

```
function App() {

  const [state, setstate] = useState({
    Name:'Hamza',
    Status: 'Comitted'
  })

  ChangeProfile=()=>{
    setState({
      Name: 'Shahwar',
      Status: 'Divorced'
    });   
    console.log('updated',state);
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{state.Name}</Text>
      <Text>{state.Status}</Text>
      <Button title="Click Me!" onPress={this.ChangeProfile} />
    </View>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Do not forget to import useState `import React,{useState} from 'react';`

Comment: one more thing need to add const with ChangeProfile function then its work fine

Comment: yes you are right, I did not compile it that's why I forgot :)

Answer (score 1):

**You have to use a Class component to use state.**

```
class App extend React.Component
 {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
     this.state={
       // enter code here
      }
 }

render(){
return(
//enter code here
  )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to this code. you should get parsing error. It should have `render()` method.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{this.state.Name}</Text>
            <Text>{this.state.Status}</Text>
            <Button title="Click Me!" onPress={this.ChangeProfile} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: state is not defined i'm getting this error

Comment: You are using functional component. In order to declare state use useState()

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state in this document they are using like above as i used and in this as well https://www.sitepoint.com/state-management-in-react-native/

Comment: If you look carefully you can see the difference. `class Blink extends Component {...` and `class Counter extends React.Component {...` both example use class based component. I gave the answer you can check it.